# What does it mean to be meet dense?

Tags: lattice-theory, posets

What does it mean that a set of principal ideals is meet dense in a lattice of all order ideals?

Comment: Context would help, but my guess without context is that every order ideal is a meet of some ideal from the dense set.

Comment: As @AndreasBlass says, it would be a good idea to indicate where you encountered this term.

Answer (score 2):

One of the standard meanings for **meet dense** is: a subset $S$ of a lattice $L$ is meet dense if every element of $L$ is a meet of elements of $S$. You seem to be applying the phrase to a situation where $L$ is the lattice of order(?) ideals of some lattice $K$, in which case it would mean that every order ideal of $K$ is the intersection of principal ideals.

But, if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable in $K$, then the order ideal $\langle a, b\rangle$ they generate will not contain $a\vee b$, while every principal ideal containing $\langle a, b\rangle$ will contain $a\vee b$. So it is impossible for the set of principal ideals of $K$ to be meet dense in the lattice of order ideals unless $K$ is a chain. Perhaps you mean *lattice ideals* of $K$ rather than *order ideals*?